# alternative asp.net login control security check

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, login-control

i started to implement my login class from scratch, and have a big problem in security

this is my algorithm for logging page:

```
if(userName and password == true)
{
    creating session from login object
    encrypt username 
    creating cookie from  encrypted username
    go to private page
}
```

and on my page_load() private page:

```
if(session existed)
{
    update cookie timeout
}
else
{
    if(cookie existed)
    {
        unencrypte value
        if(username existed from unencrypted cookie value)
        {
        create session
        update cookie timeout
        }       
    }
    else
    {
    go to logging pgae
    }
}
```

so my question:
1.does this algorithm has security problem?(because i think every one could save cookie value and created bye own, is that right? )
2.i am using cookie because i had problem for session time out, and want to keep login my user for more than a day. is that a good way?
3. what are some site like facebook do for keep log in their user?
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, everyone can create cookies, but not everyone can encrypt the value you want to set. The encryption is done server side with a private key only you, or your code, should have access to.

2) Cookie can be set to be available only during the browser session of until a specific expiration date, so yes that would be a good option.

3) I would not know for all users, but a cookie is a good option. Sites like live.com and google.com just create cookies with a long expiration date. Keep in mind that you should provide a means to let the user decide this (for instance using a checkbox).

Maybe I'm missing some context by why invent the wheel and not just use ASP.NET Forms Authentication. That will do just what U describe in your algorithm.

You can combine it with the Membership Provider Framework or the new ASP.NET Identity Framework.

Comment: thank you so much, if someone logged in for a long time, and encrypted cookie saved on the browser, every one how use the computer could see cookie value, and then in other computer could create cookie with the same value, so could see private page, that is right?

Comment: Almost. I someone could login to the same computer, and also the same system account, he or she would be able to get hold of the cookie. They will not be able to read the cookie value as it is encrypted but could use the cookie on another machine to login to the same service (identity theft).